# Bootstrap modal doesn't show up

Tags: ajax, modal-dialog

I have a modal that should be shown when the ajax success function is executed. But it doesn't show up. Here is my code. It triggers when I manually trigger using a button.

```
$.ajax
({
   type: "POST",
   url: "PHP/guestreg.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function() 
   {
     $('#success').modal('show');
   }
});
```

Comment: Could you put this up on JSfiddle along with your html code. It would easy to debug!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/asifiddle/ze2n96aL/#&togetherjs=bs3mM4EBuy